# Highcharts pie/bar combo. How to load json and how are the data series expressed

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am very confused about how to load `json` data into the combo pie / bar Highcharts. Please find the code below. Its an example and by no means finished. I just need a better grasp on the `json` load and how the data series should be expressed. Thanks in advance.

1. Please note the js code that is highlighted - is that correct? The project resides on my dev box and the `json` file is local.
2. For starters I would like to chart the Status and ID values from my `json` file. How should the series in the `js` code look?

i.e

```
name: 'id',
data: processed_json
```

**-Begin Code example html/js-**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>xxxxxxxx Automation</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
${demo.css}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    //  Load jason data
    // var processed_json = new Array();
    //$.getJSON('json_output.json', function(data) {
    //    // Populate series
    //    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    //        processed_json.push([data[i].key, data[i].value]);


    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Nightly Scheduled Smoke Test', 'New Release Test', 'Regression Test', ' Discovery Test']
        },
        labels: {
            items: [{
                html: 'xxxxxxxxx Validation',
                style: {
                    left: '55px',
                    top: '18px',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
                }
            }]
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Ad-Hoc',
            data: [3, 5, 5, 8]
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Create Order',
            data: [3, 5, 5, 8]
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Create-Express-Ready-Parameter',
            data: [3, 5, 5, 8]

        }, {
            type: 'spline',
            name: 'Average',
            data: [3, 2.67, 3, 6.33, 3.33],
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
                fillColor: 'white'
            }
        }, {
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'xxxxxxx Passed',
            data: [{
                name: 'Ad-Hoc',
                y: 13,
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] // Ad-Hoc's color
            }, {
                name: 'Create Order',
                y: 23,
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1] // Create Order's color
            }, {
                name: 'Create-Express-Ready-Parameter',
                y: 19,
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2] // Create-Express-Ready-Parameter's color
            }],
            center: [100, 80],
            size: 100,
            showInLegend: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }]
    });
});
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
<p><center>
The following XXXXXn Report illustrates current Pass validation by test category.
<p> * Green represents the number of passed scenarios
<p> * Black represents the number of scenarios that are in progress or dev/test.
<p> * Blue represents the number of failed scenarios.
</p>
</center>
</html>
```

**-snippet of json-**

```
[
  {
    "uri": "features/TC-0001-Bill-Of-Laiding-Shipping.feature",
    "id": "check-pricing-for-bill-of-laiding",
    "keyword": "Feature",
    "name": "Check Pricing for Bill of Laiding",
    "description": "",
    "line": 3,
    "tags": [
      {
        "name": "@Bill-Of-Laiding-Shipping",
        "line": 1
      }
    ],
    "elements": [
      {
        "id": "check-pricing-for-bill-of-laiding;check-pricing-for-bill-of-laiding",
        "keyword": "Scenario",
        "name": "Check Pricing for Bill of Laiding",
        "description": "",
        "line": 5,
        "type": "scenario",
        "tags": [
          {
            "name": "@Bill-Of-Laiding-Shipping",
            "line": 1
          }
        ],
        "steps": [
          {
            "keyword": "Given ",
            "name": "TC-0006-Log into One Lisa",
            "line": 7,
            "match": {
              "location": "features/step_definitions/my_steps.rb:779"
            },
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 9024120000
            }
          },
          {
            "keyword": "Then ",
            "name": "TC-0001-Bill-Of-Laiding Query onleLisa (Lisa_One) to access existing Bill Of laiding",
            "line": 8,
            "match": {
              "location": "features/step_definitions/my_steps.rb:1194"
            },
```

Comment: What do you need exactly ?

Comment: Is this  the correct code to load the json.

Comment: //  Load jason data
    // var processed_json = new Array();
    //$.getJSON('json_output.json', function(data) {
    //    // Populate series
    //    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    //        processed_json.push([data[i].key, data[i].value]);

Comment: The json is on my local development box as is the index.htm file

Comment: You need to make an array with the params which Highcharts waits.
Something like: 
var data = [
    {
     name => "you name",
    y         => "you value",
    color   => color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
    }, 
    {
     name ...
]

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help you mading your code a bit easy to understand.
You JSON, should fill the var 'dataPie' that I created.

I hope that it will help you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataPie = [
        {
            name: 'ONE PART OF PIE',
            y: 10,
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        }, {
            name: 'ANOTHER PART OF PIE',
            y: 15,
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
        }];

    var pieObject = {
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'xxxxxxx Passed',
            data: dataPie,
            center: [100, 80],
            size: 100,
            showInLegend: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }



    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Nightly Scheduled Smoke Test', 'New Release Test', 'Regression Test', ' Discovery Test']
        },
        labels: {
            items: [{
                html: 'xxxxxxxxx Validation',
                style: {
                    left: '55px',
                    top: '18px',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
                }
            }]
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Ad-Hoc',
            data: [3, 5, 5, 8]
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Create Order',
            data: [3, 5, 5, 8]
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Create-Express-Ready-Parameter',
            data: [3, 5, 5, 8]

        }, {
            type: 'spline',
            name: 'Average',
            data: [3, 2.67, 3, 6.33, 3.33],
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
                fillColor: 'white'
            }
        }, 
            pieObject
        ]
    });
})
```

Comment: Thank you: Please explain how the json is data is loaded. I was expecting something like /$.getJSON('json_output.json', function(data) {

Comment: $.get('json_output.json', function(data) {
   var items = [];
   $.each (data, function (key, val) { 
      // here you can do what you want with the json that the file returns.
   })
})

Comment: I am not being clear.  My objective is very straight forward. I just want an example of a simple chart displaying two values from the json sample provided.  I understand how the $.getJSON('json_output.json', function(data) loads the data. I would like see an example with the series capturing the specif values I am seeing endless examples and none simple show how to arrange the series. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

1) There is a [Highcharts Documentation on custom data preprocessing](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing#3) that covers loading data from JSON. If you are going to load data using jQuery's [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), then before creating the chart you should include data in chart's configuration object (used to create the chart).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline'
        },
        series: [{}]
    };
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
```

2) Series should look like described in [Documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series). The most important and most needed part is data array. To plot your chart you will need to parse your JSON data into format acceptable by Highcharts - more info in [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<line>.data).

In short - data must be 1 of 3: an array of numerical values(1), or array of arrays(2), or array of object with named properties(3). Data must cover `y` values of each point and can have additional info.

I am unable to help you with data parsing since I do not know where are required values nor what data you want to include in chart's data nor where (meaning as what - point names, additional tooltip values, series names, others?). If you will provide more info, then I could update this answer with more precise example / demo.

Comment: Thanks  all for your insight. 
I am getting a better understanding.
As for parsing the data - let’s say I have
I want my data series to represent data from the following 
Json . Of interest to me is  Status and Name. 
These are the values that I would like to see charted.
With this basic model I will be able to build  .

Comment: Status is : Passed  or failed i.e.
Name is :  "name": "TC-0001-Bill-Of-Laiding Query onleLisa (Lisa_One) to access existing Bill Of laiding",
-----------------------------------------

Comment: {
  "keyword": "Then ",
  "name": "TC-0001-Bill-Of-Laiding Query onleLisa (Lisa_One) to access existing Bill Of laiding",
  "line": 8,
  "match": {
    "location": "features/step_definitions/my_steps.rb:1194"
  },
  "result": {
    "status": "failed",

Comment: @user3233238 So y value of point should be 0 for 'failed' and 1 for 'passed'? Each step in steps array has result object, so each step is a point? Then elements array will be series? Then your main JSON is array with objects - those objects can have multiple series? What are the objects in main array? I can get single value out of complex JSON, but set up parser you should explain patter first.